# Is an app using significant location change subject to the same app submission scrutiny as an app with a UIBackgroundMode key of location?

Tags: ios

Would an app that uses a significant location change notification to wake itself up to perform a background activity be likely to be rejected from the app store?

Comment: How is this related to programming? Wouldn't asking Apple directly get you a more accurate answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would depend on what action you were performing using the location change notification. Apple is generally not forthcoming about the finer points of what is and isn't acceptible. If your app is using location, Apple will know about it during the review process and if your app does not have a legitimate reason for using location, you can assume you will get rejected.

With that said, if you DO have a legitimate reason to use the users location, there is absolutely no reason to think your app will get rejected or subjected to additional scrutiny outside the normal screening process. Rest assured, they will test your app inside and out. What happens if the user rejects location updates, what does your app do then. So do yourself a favor, and account for all possibilities. Not only is it good for your eventual users, it will make the approval process that much easier.